# Error: Return value must be of type: Iterable

Tags: apex, batch

I want to filter opportunities to grab specific set of campaigns in start method itself and pass the filtered list to the execute. I am thinking of not to use additional query in start method using Database.getQueryLocator since I already have the entire list coming in constructor. I am planning to use Iterable  as return in start method but getting following error "Return value must be of type: Iterable"

Code:

```
public Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        for(Opportunity Opp: newList){            
            //Filter incoming opportunities and grab campaignIds of the sccess opportunities into set "OriginalCampaignIds"
        }        
    return OriginalCampaignIds;
}
```

Tried below codes:

```
public List<Id> start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        for(Opportunity Opp: newList){            
            //Filter incoming opportunities and grab campaignIds of the sccess opportunities into set "OriginalCampaignIds"
        }    
    }        
    return new List<Id>(OriginalCampaignIds);
}
```

**Error**: Class must implement the global interface method: Iterable start(Database.BatchableContext) from Database.Batchable

Another Try:

```
public Iterable<Id> start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        for(Opportunity Opp: newList){            
            //Filter incoming opportunities and grab campaignIds of the sccess opportunities into set "OriginalCampaignIds"
        }       
    return new List<Id>(OriginalCampaignIds);
}
```

Same error as above

Comment: A set is not an Iterable. Convert it to a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A set is not an Iterable, covert to a list:

```
Return New List<Id>(OriginalIds);
```